# JPA Hibernate one to many... throwing constraint violation.. in unit testing

Tags: java, spring

I have picked up a legacy project, and am writing tests for them... but the tests seem to fail with constraint violation could not insert Car...

The two classes...

one class has the following mapping:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Cars.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="factory")
public List<Cars> getCars() {
    return cars;
}
```

the class on the many side has the following class:

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity=Factory.class, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="factory_id")
public Factory getFactory() {
    return factory;
}
```

This fails in my tests, using hsql.. but works fine in the SQL server when fully deployed war app apparently... have not tested it myself, but was told it does.

I think it has something to do with the the mapping of the relationship...

my stack trace:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalStateException> but was<javax.persistence.PersistenceException>
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.test.Car]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1174)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:674)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
```

logging give me the following:

```
[2013-03-19 13:27:14,330] ERROR  [      main] [    JDBCExceptionReporter] - integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_CT_10074 table: CAR
```

Comment: Can you add your test code showing how you are constructing and associating these objects.

Comment: @gkamal .. I found that if i change the oneToOne to a ManyToOne, it works fine.. why is that?.. my tests run fine...

Comment: can u show the  exception stack trace

Comment: added stack trace and logging output..

Comment: My **guess** is that this has to do with your CascadeType. Try using more granular cascading. The [individual types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html) include MERGE, REFRESH, DELETE, PERSIST, SAVE_UPDATE, REPLICATE, LOCK, and DETACH. The page also includes some deprecated methods and a pointer to the JPA javadocs. If this sorts you, indicate so and I'll post it as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @hs.. and to everyone... thanks a lot... i spoke to our senior architect.. apparently the mapping was incorrect... and my test picked it up and it seems it has never worked... legacy code.. ugh!!

Answer (score 0):

chnage to manyToOne.. and it wil work. mapping was incorrect.